# Оптимизация авторизации на высоконагруженном сайте

Tags: авторизация, php, оптимизация, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте! Сейчас авторизация осуществляется следующей командой к бд: "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `password`='{$password}' AND `login`='{$login}' "; Таблица Users высоконагружена, порядка 300000 записей, что сильно грузит систему. Подскажите пожалуйста как в данном случае следует организовать авторизацию на сайте?

Comment: А индекс по password И login есть?

Comment: Auto Incr. у ID, остальные поля пустые. Расскажите пожалуйста поподробнее про индексы

Comment: @Vladimir_7878 - [Индексы в MySQL: многоколоночные индексы против комбинированных индексов][1]

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/70640/

Comment: @Vladimir_7878, 
покажите 

    explain SELECT id FROM users WHERE password='{$password}' AND login='{$login}' "

@Чад, комбинированный индекс тут не поможет, т.к. я думаю login всё-таки уникален, соответственно пароль у него один, соответственно ищем мы в login, вот хуже если есть индекс на password, и он автоматом цепляется mysql... кроме того, вот например в таблице mysql:

http://paste.debian.net/66107/

Comment: @eicto, Вы какую-то ересь написали.

Comment: Правильно @eicto написал. Должно работать с одним индексом по login, т.к. СУБД вполне способна сначала отсечь по login (останется не более одной записи) и потом проверять password. И я думаю, это лучший вариант. Если индексов два, то не факт, что СУБД догадается, какой лучше первым выбрать. Если комбинированный, особой пользы это не даст, т.к. password, я надеюсь, - закодированный, а hash'и обычно длинные

Comment: @Михаил М, а какая разница для индекса какая длинна? Да да, СУБД тупая как пробка, она на простейшем where будет сидеть и год думать - а какой индекс бы взять...

Comment: @Чад вы пример видели ? при комбинированном индексе не используется индекс вообще, в случае если не было использовано AND, так-то.

Comment: @eicto, А Вы вопрос читали? Там то как раз AND и используется...

Comment: @Чад в этом запросе AND в другом нет... да и **объясните** мне зачем нужен индекс на password....

Comment: специально для @Чад экслюзивное исследование темы http://paste.debian.net/66230/ , там как раз рассмотрен вопрос влияния дополнительного индекса на вставку. [зачем же нужен композитный индекс ?](http://paste.debian.net/66233/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте индекс по этим полям составной.

Вот интересная статейка на эту тему: [Индексы в MySQL: многоколоночные индексы против комбинированных индексов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70640/).

[А вот статья про индексы](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html) - её полезно почитать.

**UPD**
Итак, после жаркого спора с [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), резюмирую.

Конкретно в Вашем случае, выгоднее создать индекс только по полю login. Т.к. это обеспечит вам скорость, за счёт того что login уникален (Кстати, надо наверное не просто индекс сделать, а уникальный индекс, чтобы логика не ломалась, если появятся несколько одинаковых login), и при этом добавление строчки в базу будет быстрее.

В случаях, когда login не уникален, выгоднее будет сделать индекс по login и password.

Comment: плохой совет, я указал выше почему.

Comment: Вы написали набор букв, почти бессвязный. Так что аргументируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: @eicto, Во первых - будут запросы только по логину - можно будет делать индекс только по логину. А индекс по паролю и логину нужен для ускорения проверки. Если только по логину - мы потом ещё будет сверять поле пароль. Если по паролю и логину - только в индекс сходим.

Comment: да, но исследование не по теме, если вас интересуют интересные моменты читайте блоги оптимизаторов, того-же Зайцева например. По паролю индекс не нужен, мало того я не уверен что при записи это не увеличит тормоза. Поле пароля мы всё равно будем сверять, т.к. индекс - для поиска а не для сравнения.

Comment: Не по теме чего? Не по теме "почему @eicto прав, а @Чад не прав"? Да, это статья про то как составные и комбинированные индексы влияют на производительность выборки.

Comment: я же вам говорю - **тут не  нужен комбинированный индекс**  он тут совсем не в тему. То что знаете - хорошо. К тому-же я уже говорил, ни в статье ни у вас не рассматривается момент, что индекс это не только advantage на момент выборки но и disatvantage на момент вставки.

Comment: @eicto, я понимаю Ваше утверждение, и оно полезно и я с ним в целом согласен. НО! Не в данном случае - Вопрошающий ни слова не сказал о регистрации пользователей и что она тормозит (что тормозит вставка в таблицу, да и врятли будут вставлять сразу пол ляма пользователей). А при выборке по двум полям - комбинированный индекс будет быстрее обычного. Вы случаем не фанат продукции Apple?

Comment: @Чад, я же блин показал что **не будет** в данном случае быстрее... нет я не фанат Apple. Вопрощающий не сказал, потому-что **у него ещё нет индекса**, вот сделает по вашему совету и у него вставка будет в два раза медленнее чем нужно. поэтому я вам и поставил **-**, чтобы у него не было идеи воспользоваться этим советом, а вам прокомментировал, чтобы развеять ваше недопонимание, но вы видимо хотите и дальше всю жизнь ставить индекс "на всякий случай", чтож, удачи.

Answer (score 6):

Причиной медленной работы могут быть не только "высоконагружена", "300000 записей" это очень мало. Оптимизируйте остальной php код, подключите кеширование, оптимизируйте сами таблицы - типы данных(частая ошибка новичков, которые везде суют varchar).

Answer (score 1):

Как то разделял таблицу с 80 млн. записей, которая содержала список авто запчастей и заменников. Индексирование по полям мало помогло. Клонировал таблицу с индексами 0-9 A-Z . в итоге получились таблицы формата table_a, table_b ... table_z . В каждую из таблиц запихнул строки определяемые по первому символу. Если индексирование полей login/password не принесут желаемого прироста производительности, рекомендую сделать разделение. Также определил максимальную длину строки и поле articl из varchar сделал фиксированым char . Лучше потерять место на диске (хотя не так уже и много было потеряно, несколько десятков мегабайт), зато повысилась скорость чтения данных.

Comment: Если индексирование мало помогло, то хреновые индексы были :-) Или запросы через одно место... :-) Кластеризация должна выполнятся на уровне СУБД а не "мега" архитектурой БД. Если в СУБД написано что оно держит N записей - значит она держит N записей.

Comment: @Чад, ещё года три назад были популярны статьи на тему "Why mysql suxx on over 1M records" там куча причин была, всё в принципе чинится, но вот так просто индексы прописать не всегда помогает.

Comment: @eicto, так оно же не стоит на месте. Давай те ещё 80мидесятые вспомним.... Но индексы просто так прописывать не надо :-)